# How to import scrapy-user-agents with conda

Tags: scrapy, conda

The package can't be installed with conda install command and its documentation shows only the pip install.

This is the error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - scrapy-user-agent

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: What is your question? If a package is not available in any `conda` channel then it cannot be installed with `conda`.

Comment: It is not hosted on https://anaconda.org under any public channel.  You can still use pip via `pip install conda-user-agents`

Comment: Do i run this cmd from my conda terminal ??